# Need some help understanding Vocabulary of Interlinked Dataset (VoID) in Linked Open Data

Tags: metadata, sparql, linked-data, opendata

I have been trying to understand VoID in Linked Open Data. It would be great if anyone could help clarify some of my confusions.

- Does it need to be stored in a separate file or it can be included in the RDF dataset itself? If so, how do I query it? (A sample query would be really helpful)
- How is the information in VoID used in real life?

Answer (score 2):

> - Does it need to be stored in a separate file or it can be included in the RDF dataset itself? If so, how do I query it? (A sample query would be really helpful)

In theory not, but for practical purposes yes. In the end the information is encoded in triples, so it doesn't really matter in what file you put them and you could argue that it's best to actually put the VoID info into the data files and serve these triples with your data as meta-info. It's query-able as all other forms of RDF, either load it into some SPARQL endpoint or use a library that can directly load RDF files. This however also shows the reason why a separate file makes sense: instead of having to load potentially large data files just to get some dataset meta info, it makes sense to offer the meta-data in its own file.

> - How is the information in VoID used in real life?

VoID is actually used in several scenarios already, but mostly a recommendation and a good idea. The most prominent use-cases i know of is to get your dataset shown in the [LOD Cloud](http://lod-cloud.net/#how-to-join). You currently have to register it with [datahub.io](https://datahub.io) and add a VoID file ([example from my associations dataset](https://datahub.io/dataset/associations/resource/e20a2886-bca6-4f49-a50f-9e41449935c3)).

Other examples (sadly many defunct nowadays) can be found here: http://semanticweb.org/wiki/VoID.html

Comment: Besides needing it for the registration in datahub, are there other practical uses of VoID?

Comment: added a link to a wiki mentioning some further use-cases... mostly i'd say it's a recommendation to allow cool(er) stuff in the future

Comment: So, is it safe to say that, for now at least, there is not much significance of VoID?

Comment: Well, that totally depends on who you are and what your horizon is... if you're a researcher and look into the future striving to make the world a better place, i'd say VoID is a pretty cool idea and significant. It allows you to describe a dataset on a meta level. If you measure on a current monetary scale, it's probably not worth your time... but so is any research in its infancy (think of cryptography in maths) ;)